# Angular Seed - Install bower_components on the same directory folder level as app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, angular-seed

So I recently used [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) in a code challenge as part of a job interview process.  I got dinged for keeping bower_components inside the app folder.

**Question 1:** Is this really such a bad practice - to keep bower_components inside the app folder?

After getting dinged, I decided to install bower_components on the same level as the app folder.  But of course, all the references in index.html no longer made sense since the references expected bower_components to be inside the app folder.

**Question 2:** How would I reference the bower_components outside the app folder? Would this need to be part of a build step to copy app to a ./public folder, then copy bower_compnents into ./public/app, then start the server and tell it to serve static files from ./public/app?

I modified the "prestart" command to accomplish this, but it just didn't *feel* right.  And then there's also the issue of making changes in the app folder and then having to restart the server every time to see my changes in the browser.

What's the best practice here? I know the yeoman generator keeps bower_components outside the project root and a gulp/grunt task corrects the references, but I like angular-seed because it's pretty minimal and I'd like to just use npm for build tasks.

Comment: There is nothing in the angular-seed that is suggesting bower_components will be placed inside the app folder

Comment: There is this: "Note that the bower_components folder would normally be installed in the root folder but angular-seed changes this location through the .bowerrc file. Putting it in the app folder makes it easier to serve the files by a webserver."  And this in .bowerrc: `{
  "directory": "app/bower_components"
}`

Comment: ah sorry, I looked at it a couple times and didn't see that.

Comment: no worries! all learning here.  =)

Comment: That being said, I do not think there is really a "correct" answer to your question. It all depends on the workflow you have created yourself. Generally you do not want to expose bower_components or anything similar on the server as that could create possible attack vectors. But what you do on the client-side is really up to you.

Comment: If you have made a mental distinction where bower_components will only contain dependencies that are part of the client-side application, then there isn't anything neccessarily wrong with placing it in the /app folder. If for instance node_modules was placed there, it could eventually be a nuisance to have to traverse paths from outside of app, or have to exclude node_modules when only dealing with client-side code inside app.

Comment: Basically, it's all about your workflow, do you have to jump through all kinds of hoops to accomplish simple things like copying files, referencing files etc? Than perhaps your structure isn't well fitted for your workflow

Comment: An example of a workflow is, let's assume that you do serve bower_components as a static middleware, now you have to jump through hoops locally to mimic that behavior on the server. So the question then becomes, why not create a folder structure that is more identical to the server, than have to copy and move files around because you decided on this folder structure

Comment: yeah, i see what you're saying.  I guess I'm just being a bit obsessed about why I got dinged in my code challenge! So I'm just trying to determine what is a best practice and how to implement that.

Comment: I would ask for feedback next time. Good practice is to have a /src folder that only contains your code, and the root serves as your package configuration. So perhaps they felt you did not separate concerns very well by mixing your source code with dependencies. But it's anyone's guess

Answer (score 0):

It's best to keep `bower_components`outside app folder, same as `node_modules`.

They are both package managers. Use `.bowerrc` to set paths: ([docs](https://bower.io/docs/config/))

```
{
  "directory": "public/app/js"
}
```

`bower install` will place all files in bower.json in the set directory.

---

Alternatively, if you use grunt, you can look at how yeoman generator-angular uses grunt to minify and clean up bower scripts/css.

```
    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
```

[Gruntfile.js looks like this.](https://gist.github.com/teachtyler/3aa282a8af914c1befdbe834a8e1e7b9)
(The Gruntfile is generated when you use `yo angular`)

When you use `grunt build` it concatenates your index.html, clones everything to a dist folder and the scripts become:

```
<script src="scripts/vendor.2bed74dc.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/scripts.f9d73ac6.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, this part I get.  But I'm trying to use just npm as a task runner.  I'm also using (as part of angular-seed), the cli http-server, so I don't think (not 100% sure) there's a way for me to use connect middleware to reference bower_components without modifying http-server's code.  Thanks for your answer, appreciate the added reassurance that bower_components should be outside the app folder.